# How can i create an custom post template for an specific post category in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i need to create an custom template for childs of the a  specific category.
Is possible ?

Comment: This is a question that's better asked on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could add a conditional in your `category.php` or `archive.php` file for getting your custom template if url match the category or add a function in your `functions.php` theme. An example for the latest, where *template_cat_c.php* is your custom template:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'template_cat' );

function template_cat( $template ) {
  if ( is_subcategory_from($parent_id) ) {
    return 'template_cat_c.php';
  } else {
    return $template;
  }
}
```

Check the function there: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89512/wordpress-function-like-is-category-for-subcategory-is-subcategory to make the *is_subcategory_from($parent_id)*.